# BLE wasn't working in the background under iOS9

Tags: swift, background, bluetooth-lowenergy, ios9, appdelegate

I'm a long-time lurker at Stack Overflow, and joined up today just to post a solution to a problem that has vexed me for weeks, for which I haven't seen the solution anywhere else. Maybe someone else will be helped.

We have an iOS app written in Swift that uses a vendor-supplied SDK to communicate with a specific BLE device.  The problem was that iOS would pause the app when it moved into the background rather than leave it running, but would only do this under iOS9.  Under iOS10 & 11, everything worked fine in the background.

At first I figured the vendor needed to tweak their SDK code, but their sample application worked fine in the background on iOS9.

Cutting to the chase: our app was instantiating the BLE worker class from within AppDelegate, since it needs to run independently of whatever view is currently displayed on the screen.  It finally dawned on me that the biggest difference between our app and the vendor's sample app was that they instantiated the BLE scanning, etc., from within a view controller class.

I modified the code to instantiate the BLE worker object from within the viewDidLoad event of the first view controller, and then set a reference to it in AppDelegate.  That did the trick.  I'm guessing that iOS9 needs the BLE code to be tied to the main UI processing thread, rather than AppDelegate, in order to know to allow the app to continue to run in the background.

So if you need to communicate with a BLE device when your app is backgrounded, and backgrounding doesn't work for iOS9 devices only, make sure you instantiate the BLE communication from within a View Controller class.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Answering your own question is perfectly OK, but you should stick with the Question and Answer format; ie. State your problem in the question and then provide an answer to that question.  Can you provide some information on how you were creating your CBCentral object?  It should not be necessary to do it in a view controller, but it does need to be associated with the run loop.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on proper protocol, Paul.  I'll try to edit the post later today per your suggestion, and include more details.  In fact, I wanted to include more details in my original post, but had started the upgrade of Xcode from 9 to 9.0.1 and so couldn't get to the code right then.